# Allocate memory with mmap for N integer

Tags: c, linux

let's say i have this line of code :

```
int PAGESIZE = getpagesize(); // returns 4096
int* shared_mm = mmap(NULL,PAGESIZE,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
```

this mean that i get 4096 bytes, so i can store 1024 integer (4096/4), right?

so if i need to save N values of type int, i'm gonna have to do :

```
PAGESIZE = N * 4;
```

and pass it into the mmap function, knowing that it will round it to a multiple of 4096 if it isn't, am i getting this right?

Comment: I would probably do `PAGESIZE = N * sizeof(int)` to be absolutely sure. Int size may vary for different systems.

Comment: "this mean that i get 4096 bytes, so i can store 1024 integer (4096/4), right?" It depends. There is now space allocated (maybe not assigned yet) to store at least 4096 integers, when you are ok that a integer may (or may more, depending on the system) has a range of 0-255 and not anything else.

Comment: Please do not name variables with ALLCAPS.  C allows it, but that naming style is conventionally reserved for preprocessor macros and enum constants. Using it for other kinds of identifiers makes your code difficult and confusing for others to read.

Comment: It works exactly like [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), in fact malloc it self, more likely call to this function, depending what kind of memory alocator you are using. By default with glibc it is [pdmalloc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/The-GNU-Allocator.html). Some implementations use brk/sbrk instead. So in order to access a memory block cast `void*` to `int*` and then `shared_mm[100] = 4`  or use pointer arithmetic. For matrix use `mhared_mm[ (i * width) + j] = 4`  or cast to same rules for tensors etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `int` may or may not be 4 bytes. That's a common size, but it's only guaranteed to be at least 2 bytes<sup>[1]</sup>.

So the correct expression would be

```c
PAGESIZE = N * sizeof( int );
```

It's just like when using `malloc`. The length passed to `mmap` does not need to be a multiple of the page size.

---

1. Assuming 8-bit bytes, but that's a given now.